# Estimating the error for $e-(1+\frac 1n)^n$

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

I would like to estimate the error $e-(1+\frac 1n)^n$, for arbitrary $n \ge 0$. I think I have found a way to do it, but it does not really seem optimal to me. Here is what I did:

I considered the function $f : [0,\frac 1n]$, $f(0) = (1+\frac 1n)^n$ and $f(x) = e^{nx}+(1+\frac 1n)^n-(1+x)^{\frac 1 x} $

This function is continuous and I have $\exists \theta \in \left(0,\frac 1 n\right ): $

$$ e-(1+\frac 1n)^n=f \left (\frac 1n\right ) - f(0) = \frac 1 n f'(\theta)  $$

by the mean value theorem. However, $f'(\theta)$ seems a bit too complicated. I tried simplifying it and bounding it from above, involving $n$, but it does not simplify a lot.

Any hints on maybe choosing another function that allows a smoother estimation? Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Taylor and binomial theorem perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=\frac{1}{n}$. Then $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n=(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}$. Take the logarithm to get

$$\ln\left[(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}\right]=\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}=1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3}-\cdots+\frac{(-x)^n}{n+1}+\cdots.$$

Exponentiate back to get

\begin{align}
\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n&=e\exp\left(-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3}-\cdots+\frac{(-x)^n}{n+1}+\cdots\right)\\
&=e\left(1-\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{11}{24n^2}-\frac{7}{16n^3}+\cdots\right),\quad
n\gg 1.
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Bounding $f'(\theta)$ when $\theta = \frac1n$ seems to reduce to estimating the error you started with again, with some other complicating terms, so I don't think that's a good approach.

The standard approach I've seen for *bounding* the error is to show that $$\left(1 + \frac1n\right)^n < e < \left(1 + \frac1n\right)^{n+1}$$ which can be done by starting with $e^x \ge 1 + x$ and doing lots of manipulations. This tells us that, in particular,
$$\frac{e}{1 + \frac1n} < \left(1 + \frac1n\right)^n < e$$ so the error is at most $e - \frac{e}{1 + \frac1n} < \frac en$.

But if you want an estimate rather than a bound on the error (I think it turns out to be on the order of $\frac{e}{2n}$) you need other tools.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n+1} \geq e \geq (1+\frac{1}{n})^n$

So $e -(1+\frac{1}{n})^n \leq (1+\frac{1}{n})^{n+1}-(1+\frac{1}{n})^n = (1+\frac{1}{n})^n (1+\frac{1}{n}-1) = \frac{(1+\frac{1}{n})^n}{n} \leq \Huge{\frac{e}{n}} $

Done.